# My function seems to only return undefined values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append my function `GetQuotes()` to a button. Every time you click the button, it displays new text, or in this case, new quotes. Currently, the button only displays an answer that is `undefined`.

My logic was to create an array with strings of quotes.  I first tried using a `for` loop to generate random quotes to appear.  However, that clearly didn't make any sense.  I then used `Math.random()` to generate random quotes. I then tried appended it my `h2` class called `stuff`.  The button is called `quotes`.  When you click the button it changes the text in the `h2`.

Here is the Javascript:

```
function getQuotes(){ 
  var quotes = [ 
    "Thousands of candles can be lighted from a single candle, and the life of the candle will not be shortened. Happiness never decreases by being shared.Buddha",
    "Happiness is the art of never holding in your mind the memory of any unpleasant thing that has passed.Unknown",
    "To be happy, we must not be too concerned with others.Albert Camus",
    "If you want happiness for an hour — take a nap.If you want happiness for a day — go fishing.If you want happiness for a year — inherit a fortune.If you want happiness for a lifetime — help someone else."
  ]

  var result = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 

  document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = result; 
}
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#quotes', function() {
    document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = getQuotes();
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12-xs">
    <h2 id="stuff" class="text-center"><em> Here is some Text </em> </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#stuff').html(getQuotes());

Comment: Inside your function, remove `document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = result;` and replace it with `return result;`

Comment: Can you explain why that worked?

Comment: @Codes316 Sure - The function didn't return anything and you set the value of the `H2` element inside the function, ruther than returning the value to the `click` event (Where you expect the value from the function when you set `document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = getQuotes();`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything, so JS will give you `undefined` instead. Because the last line of your function is setting the element directly, then the jQuery handler is setting it again (to undefined), you'll end up losing the value and only seeing undefined.

What you are currently doing is essentially:

```
// as part of getQuotes:
  document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = result; 
  // return undefined;

// in the handler
document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = undefined; // the output from getQuotes
```

You can **either** change your function to:

```
function getQuotes(){ 
  var quotes = [ "Thousands of candles can be lighted from a single candle, and the life of the candle will not be shortened. Happiness never decreases by being shared.Buddha",
"Happiness is the art of never holding in your mind the memory of any unpleasant thing that has passed.Unknown",
"To be happy, we must not be too concerned with others.Albert Camus",
"If you want happiness for an hour — take a nap.If you want happiness for a day — go fishing.If you want happiness for a year — inherit a fortune.If you want happiness for a lifetime — help someone else."]

return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 
}
```

**or you can** leave the `innerHTML = foo` in your function and change the jQuery handler to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#quotes', function() {
    getQuotes();
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

`getQuotes` should `return result` at the end instead of setting the innerHTML of the `stuff` div.

As it stands, `getQuotes` is settings the innerHTML of the `stuff` div and returning `undefined` (since it doesn't have an explicit return statement). After that happens, your onclick handler is overwriting the innerHTML with `undefined`

Alternatively, you could just set the innerHTML from `getQuotes` and not in your click handler, but I don't think that's a good idea, since it makes your `getQuotes` function harder to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything, so when you set the value of innerhtml to the value of the required quote it does it first time but then as the function is not returning anything, undefined it returned from the function which is set to the innerhtml in the jquery code.
You can do the following change to the code :-

```js
function getQuotes(){ 
  var quotes = [ 
    "Thousands of candles can be lighted from a single candle, and the life of the candle will not be shortened. Happiness never decreases by being shared.Buddha",
    "Happiness is the art of never holding in your mind the memory of any unpleasant thing that has passed.Unknown",
    "To be happy, we must not be too concerned with others.Albert Camus",
    "If you want happiness for an hour — take a nap.If you want happiness for a day — go fishing.If you want happiness for a year — inherit a fortune.If you want happiness for a lifetime — help someone else."
  ]

  var result = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; 

  return result; 
}
```